# Shortcut key to jump to "files to include" input in Find In Files

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I use the keyboard shortcut for Find in Files (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), and use other hotkeys, like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to toggle regex matching on/off (though I wish they'd used the same shortcuts as Visual Studio!

In Visual Studio you can jump to the File Types input with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, but I can't figure out a way to do it in VS Code, I have to resort to pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> 5 times. Anyone know the keyboard shortcut to jump directly to that input?

Comment: I see you can change the toggleFindRegex shortcut, I'm a little happier :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

New answer:
Up/down arrows now navigate the history of each search field. You can use cmd+up/down to switch between the inputs.

Original answer:
You can use the up/down arrows to switch between these inputs.

Comment: Wow I'm embarrassed I didn't try that :| Thanks @Rob!

Comment: This is no longer working for me, perhaps they changed it in a recent release of Code? However CTRL+TAB works

Comment: And if it's not on use, just check the `workbench.action.search.toggleQueryDetails` keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

VSCode 1.70 (July 2022) adds a related feature:

> ### [Search Editor: Allow Keyboard Shortcut for File to Include/Exclude](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/153684)
>
> In the search editor, there is `search.action.focusQueryEditorWidget` to focus on the query.
> I'd like to be able to set a keyboard shortcut to focus on "`files to include`" and "`files to exclude`".
>
> Fixed with [PR 153954](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/153954)
>
> This adds keybindings to quickly focus on files to include/exclude.
>
> I tried to follow the pattern for the toggle X keybindings, so I went with:
>
> - <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and
> - <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.
>
> I used "<kbd>F</kbd>" for "files".

This is available in [VSCode insiders today](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

Answer (score 1):

After inspecting context keys as suggested in the @VonC's answer, I found a `searchInputBoxFocus` context key. Reverse search among all keybindings reveals that after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open search, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to switch to the next input - the "files to include" - without five <kbd>Tab</kbd>s.

Comment: Good catch. Upvoted.